# Find all integers $m,n$ such that $(562-5(m+n))(82-5(m-n))=98^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integers $m,n$ such that $$(562-5(m+n))(82-5(m-n))=98^2.$$

What is a simpler method to tackle this? I know the results but my approach is kind of lengthy. I considered every possible factor of $98^2$ to get the result. Thanks.

Comment: $98^2$ only has $8$ factorizations into two factors.  That does not seem like many to me.  You could automate the solution from a factorization into $m,n$ easily in a spreadsheet.

Comment: @RossMillikan I get more than eight factorizations. Don't forget that one is allowed factors which are negative integers here. Also both factors are $\equiv2\pmod5$ which will narrow the possibilities down a bit.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown:  $98^2=2^2\cdot 7^4$ has $(2+1)(4+1)=15$ factors.  If you want a factorization into two factors, each one has a pair except $98$, so there are eight.

Comment: $98^2$ has thirty factors in $\Bbb Z$. @RossMillikan

Comment: I think you have other (m, n) if you considered negative factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(562-5S)(82-5D)=98^2=2^2\cdot7^4$$ The number $98^2$ has $15$ divisors, 
$$d\in\{1,2,4,7,14,28,49,98,196,343,686,1372,2401,4802,9604\}$$
Because of $82-5D=d\iff82-d=5D$,  it follows that the only divisors to be considered are $d\in\{2,7,1372,4802\}$.

It follows the possibilities
$$(D,S)\in\{(16,-848),(15,-162),(-162,15),(-848,16)\}$$

From which the only solution $\color{red}{(m,n)=(-416,-432)}$

Comment: The only red solution corresponds to $$(D,S)=(m-n,m+n)=(16,-848)$$ The others three possibilities are non compatible.

Comment: (m, n) = (84, 48) makes -98*-98. (-416, 528) makes 2 * 4802. Both make 9604 = 98*98. Are they wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From $562-5(m+n)=a, 82-5(m-n)=b$ one gets $m=\frac {644 -a -b}{10}, n=\frac {480-a + b}{10}$ therefore $10 | (a-b)$ where $a\cdot b = 98^2$. There are 30 factorizations of $98^2$ over integers, just filter out those not satisfying $10 | (a-b)$ condition, you'll only get a few remaining.

Comment: Is it a + b % 10 = 4 other than 10|(a-b)?

Comment: It should be (a + b) % 10 = 4 to make  $\frac{{644 - (a + b)}}{10}$ integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be $562 - 5(m + n)$ $=$ $a$. Let $b$ be $82 - 5(m - n)$ $=$ $b$.

Now, you check if the last digit of $a$ has $2$ or $-8$ because it has to be $(a - 562)$ % $5$ $=$ $0$ where $m, n$ $\in$ $Z$. Therefore you should check just $2$ or $-28$, $-98$, $1372$, $4802$ are one of the factor from the combinations of $(2^2)$$・$$(7^4)$

And, where $a$: $-28$ : ($-2^2$・$7$), $b$: $-7^3$, where $a$: $1372$:($2^2$・$7^3$) $b$: $7$.

Now, $(-7^3 - 82)$ % $5$ $\ne$ $0$ and whrere $a = 1372$ and $b = 7$. = $0$ will not make $m$, $n$ $\notin$ $Z$ since $m = \frac{177}{2}$, $n = \frac{147}{2}$ . So, you only need to consider the $a = 2, -98, 4802.$ The answers are  $(m, n) = (84, 48)$$[a = -98, b = -98]$, $(-416, 528)$$[a = 2, b = 4802]$, $(-416, -432)$$[a = 4802, b = 2]$.

Comment: Using FindInstance[ ] in Mathematica 10.0 only finds  m = -416, n = -432.

Comment: @Tom Dickens Thank you for checking I appreciate it, Obviously I made some miscalculations. Using the same method a = -98 , (m, n) = (84, 48), a = 2:, (-416, 528), a =
 4802: (-416, -432).