# The different interpretations to one question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integers $m,n$ such that $$(562-5(m+n))(82-5(m-n))=98^2.$$

[Find all integers $m,n$ such that $(562-5(m+n))(82-5(m-n))=98^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462448/find-all-integers-m-n-such-that-562-5mn82-5m-n-982/2462563?noredirect=1#comment5090073_2462563)

I have my answer to the question above.
Now, my question is there are four different interpretations to this question. I have my answer which satisfies the equation. Although other users' answers are more beautiful and persuading, and they have different answers to $(m, n)$.  It's like the movie Rashomon. What should I rely upon?

I solved and found  $(m, n) = (84, 48)$, $(-416, 528)$, $(-416, -432)$ considering $30$ diviors of $98^2$ in the way described below. But one user state the answer is $(m, n)$ = $(-416, -432).$ considering $15$divisors of $98^2$ ising his method similar to mine. However, other user states "$562-5(m+n)=a, 82-5(m-n)=b$ $\Rightarrow$ $m=\frac {644 -a -b}{10}, n=\frac {480-a + b}{10}$ therefore $10 | (a-b)$ where $a\cdot b = 98^2$. There are $30$ factorizations of $98^2$ over integers, just filter out those not satisfying $10 | (a-b)$ condition" In this case, this one is the most upvoted answer though, I don't know why I don't have to consider $(a + b) $%$ 10$ $=$ $4$. Furthermore, the other user state using Mathematica $10.0$(powerful software) gives $m = -416, n = -432.$.

I would like to this question since I have already asked the other users' could provide the reason why we have different answers. Unfortunately, I assume probably they might be too busy to respond it.

Thank you.

Appendix: My answer to the original post.

Let $a$ be $562 - 5(m + n)$ $=$ $a$. Let $b$ be $82 - 5(m - n)$ $=$ $b$.

Now, you check if the last digit of $a$ has $2$ or $-8$ because it has to be $(a - 562)$ % $5$ $=$ $0$ where $m, n$ $\in$ $Z$. Therefore you should check just $2$ or $-28$, $-98$, $1372$, $4802$ are one of the factor from the combinations of $(2^2)$$・$$(7^4)$

And, where $a$: $-28$ : ($-2^2$・$7$), $b$: $-7^3$, where $a$: $1372$:($2^2$・$7^3$) $b$: $7$.

Now, $(-7^3 - 82)$ % $5$ $\ne$ $0$ and whrere $a = 1372$ and $b = 7$. = $0$ will not make $m$, $n$ $\notin$ $Z$ since $m = \frac{177}{2}$, $n = \frac{147}{2}$ . So, you only need to consider the $a = 2, -98, 4802.$ The answers are  $(m, n) = (84, 48)$$[a = -98, b = -98]$, $(-416, 528)$$[a = 2, b = 4802]$, $(-416, -432)$$[a = 4802, b = 2]$.

Comment: there are these:  m: -416 n: -432 left: 4802 right: 2  ////
 m: -416 n: 528 left: 2 right: 4802  ////
 m: 84 n: 48 left: -98 right: -98  ////  Those seem to be all.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for checking! I don’t know why the OP and the answerer(Mathematica) did not check negative ones yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the two parts of the LHS of the original equation is useful, $a:= 562-5(m+n)$ and $b:=82-5(m-n) $ with $ab=98^2$.

And your answer is correct. For another view of the process, I have laid out my approach which is slightly different again, reducing the possibilities to consider wherever possible.

You can see that $(m+n)$ and $(m-n)$ (and thus $a$ and $b$) are either both odd or both even, and we need at least one of $a,b$ even so both must be. Since $98=2\cdot 7^2$, this reduces the factor pairs to consider down to just  $(98,98)$, $(14,686)$ and $(2,4802)$ and their negative counterparts. Considering the requirement to have both factors $\equiv 2 \bmod 10$, from the form of $a$ and $b$, we reduce further to $(-98,-98)$ and $(2,4802)$ (in either order).

These will define the three solutions as you can calculate $(m,n)$ directly from these:

\begin{array}{c|r}
(a,b) & m+n & m-n & m & n \\ \hline
(-98,-98) & 132 & 36 & 84 & 48 \\[1pt]
(2,4802) & 112 & -944 & -416 & 528 \\[1pt]
(4802,2) & -848 & 16 & -416 & -432 \\[1pt]
\end{array}

Comment: Yeah, it's more concise than mine. I should consider " both factors $\equiv 2 \bmod 10$" for $98^2$ $\equiv 4 \bmod 10$ to reduce the step next time. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, the $2\bmod 10$ requirement follows from the $a$ and $b$ formulas once $m{+}n$ and $m{-}n$ are found to be even.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. It helps me understand this one, too.